# Java program dynamic loading mysql

Tags: java, mysql, connection-pooling

I need to load data from `MySQL` to my Java Program. Not only load but also (`UPDATE`, `INSERT`, `DELETE` etc.) It's a **Dynamic** program so every new record has to be shown. The program layout will look something like this:
[image]

All panels are separated in their own classes.
My question is: How should I create the structure of `MySQL` connection?

- Should I create connection for each panel?
- Should I create a centralized connection class that will update data for all panels?
- What is the best practice with MySQL connection in this type of programs?
- Is there any specific Plugins for this task?

How would an experienced Java programer proceed?

**I hope that your answers will help other new Java programers to.**

Thanks.

Comment: go for Connection pooling

Answer (score 0):

you can manage your connection by using the connection pool, you can also use caching mechanism for reduce the number of hits on your database specially for the view, what I will do I will load the data in the cache and then I will move it to the view, by doing so you enhance the performance of showing the data since it will be in the cache, when the use do update or insert I will evaluate the cache area again.